# django media files on develop

Tags: django, media

im using Django 1.5.1 / python 2.7.3
also virtualenv

and i can`t corrertly delegate my media to 'django.contrib.staticfiles.views', where stored files, that was uploaded in admin interface by app django-ckeditor

static files serving well, but media (user images) not well. e.g. it returns

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/home/raido/dev/project/project/media/Raido/2013/08/28/4bebf51c0a5b.jpg
```

and if i adjust link to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Raido/2013/08/28/4bebf51c0a5b.jpg` anyway it returns 404, with debug about my urls

my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from lessons.views import LessonListView, LessonDetailView
from ckeditor import urls 

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', LessonListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', LessonDetailView.as_view()),
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
) 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
    )
```

settings.py

```
import os
_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/raido/dev/project/project/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/raido/dev/project/project/static"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (    
    ...
    os.path.join(_PATH, 'static'),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(_PATH, 'templates'),
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   ....
   'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "/home/user/dev/project/project/media/"
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
```

my tree -L 4

```
.
├── deploy
│   └── nginx
│       ├── project.conf
│       └── projectDeploy.conf
├── favicon.ico
├── lessons
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── lessons
│   │       ├── lesson_detail.html
│   │       └── lesson_list.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── logs
│   ├── nginx_access.log
│   └── nginx_error.log
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── Raido
│       └── 2013
│           └── 08
├── news
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings_deploy.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── foundation.css
│   │   │   ├── foundation.min.css
│   │   │   └── normalize.css
│   │   ├── humans.txt
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── foundation
│   │   │   ├── foundation.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery.js
│   │   │   └── vendor
│   │   └── robots.txt
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   ├── 500.html
│   │   └── base.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── pids
├── README.md
└── stati
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
                   # url(r'^admin/doc/',
                   # include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

                   ....


                   ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

this is how i serve my media

Comment: thanks, this adjust my urls. and this code must be intended... but its not solved media serve

Comment: you need also "django.core.context_processors.media" in your  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS